# SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number when using proxy

Tags: python, ssl

I'm using instauto to post pictures on Instagram using proxy. Besides, when I turn off my proxy, everything works fine. However, when I turn my proxy on it gives me this error

```
    ERROR:instauto.api.actions.request:Exception while sending request to https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/zr/token/result/?device_id=android-8cbc4322841e6ac5&token_hash=&custom_device_id=f9c6a86b-8cbc-4322-841e-6ac5d09d5ffc&fetch_reason=token_expired with data: 
 {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 502, in _connect_tls_proxy
    ssl_context=ssl_context,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1045)
```

the whole code is:

```
from instauto.api.client import ApiClient
from instauto.api import structs as st
from instauto.api.actions import post as ps

if __name__ == '__main__':
  if os.path.isfile('./.instauto.save'):
      client = ApiClient.initiate_from_file('./.instauto.save')
  else:
      client = ApiClient(user_name=os.environ.get("INSTAUTO_USER") or "my_username", password=os.environ.get("INSTAUTO_PASS") or "my_password")
      client.login()
      client.save_to_disk('./.instauto.save')

  post = ps.PostFeed(
      path='./test_feed.jpg',
      caption='This is an example. Follow me!'
  )
  resp = client.post_post(post, 80)
  print("Success: ", resp.ok)
```

I have searched to solve this problem but I failed :(. In addition, I'm not sure whether this issue from proxy ( which seems works fine ) or Instagram.

Comment: *"... proxy ( which seems works fine ) ..."* - how do you know? This kind of problem usually comes from a proxy which is not willing or capable to proxy HTTPS or from a wrong proxy configuration.  There is nothing known about configuration and proxy though.

Comment: Hi, I tried it with requests to get pictures from a URL and it's working smoothly. However, with this package, it is not working and I contacted the developer and he says that it is not from the package

Comment: So, you tried a different thing (get pictures vs. post pictures) which likely required a different URL (maybe HTTP vs. HTTPS?) and conclude from this that the proxy is working? Maybe this is the wrong conclusion. And again, nothing is known about the proxy itself and how you configured your program to use it.

Comment: Actually, I found that this problem can happen if the proxy does not support HTTPS. However, I contacted the provider of proxy and he told me that the proxy supports HTTP & HTTPS so I don't know what I should do.

Comment: I say it the last time and then I give up trying to get the necessary information from you: *"again, nothing is known about the proxy itself and how you configured your program to use it"*. There is simply nothing to reproduce without these information.

Comment: sorry if I don't understand very well. Are trying to know why I'm using a proxy? because I'm using an VPS to post photos to Instagram so I'm afraid of getting banned from Instagram so I'm using a proxy.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to __reproduce__ what you are doing. Since the problem only happens when you use a proxy you must show __how__ (not why) you use the proxy and must provide the specific proxy you use. Note that many proxies on some offered proxy lists don't actually support HTTPS, so the claim *"... he told me that the proxy supports HTTP & HTTPS ..."* might actually be wrong. Only, this is hard to tell without knowing the proxy.

Comment: Hi, Got you, I bought a social media proxy from a website called highproxies and since I'm using windows server 2019, I put the proxy information in settings > network > proxy and setup proxy manually. and then put the host and the port and clicked in save button. and then run the code I sent above. Should I give you the host and the port to reproduce the error?

Comment: Let me guess: you gave the proxy URL as `https://host:port` while it probably should have been `http://host:port`. Note that a HTTPS proxy will not necessarily have a `https://` URL but usually only `http://` - the connection will still be encrypted between client and server.

Comment: If you talking about the test I did, it was HTTP. However, for the code above I'm not sure if it is using HTTPS or HTTP for login to Instagram. and If you talking about setup the proxy I just did the host (000.000.00.00) port (0000), I tried to do it as a script but it is not working Idk why for HTTP & HTTPS in the windows settings. It only works If I did setup proxy manaully.